# Why can't I reference self.text_1 in the constructor from my kv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on a simple Kivy Popup and I'm confused as to why I can't reference my class variable, 'self.text_1', from within the constructor of the Popup class, but I can do so with the variable 'self.title'.

First, I'll start with the ubiquitous, "I'm new to Python and Kivy, so perhaps I'm just missing something obvious, but I'm at a loss."

I've tried to find answers, but nothing so far has seemed to cover this topic, at least in a way that I can understand and draw the connection. Below is my problem and some simplified code for demonstration.

From within the kv file > Label widget > text, I can refer to 'text_1' from the CustomPopup class in my py file by using 'root.text_1' when the variable is placed outside of the constructor (either before or after), but I cannot do so when placed within. The 'self.title' variable is setup the exact same way as 'self.text_1', but I CAN get that value without issue.

If I un-comment this line, using 'root.text_1' in the kv file returns the correct value.

```
class CustomPopup( Popup ):
    # I can reference this text from the kv file using "root.text_1"
    # text_1 = 'blah blah blah'
```

If instead I try to use 'self.text_1' from within the constructor, I get an Attribute error. However, I have no issues using the variable 'self.title' just below 'self.text_1'.

AttributeError: 'CustomPopup' object has no attribute 'text_1'

```
def __init__( self, foo = 'bar' ):
    super().__init__()
    self.foo =  foo

    # I can't reference this text from the kv file using "root.text_1". Why?
    self.text_1 = 'blah blah {foo}'.format( foo = self.foo )

    # I can reference this text from the kv file using "root.title"
    self.title = 'Title {foo}!'.format( foo = self.foo )
```

What is the difference here as to why I can get the value from one constructor variable, but not another with ostensibly similar syntax?

I'm using Python 3.7.1 (conda version : 4.5.12) and Kivy 1.10.1.

Python:

```
import kivy
from kivy import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


kivy.require( '1.10.1' )


Config.set( 'graphics', 'fullscreen', 0 )
Config.set( 'graphics', 'height', 600 )
Config.set( 'graphics', 'width', 800 )
Config.set( 'graphics', 'resizable', 0 )
Config.set( 'kivy', 'exit_on_escape', 0 )


class CustomPopup( Popup ):
    # I can reference this text from the kv file using "root.text_1"
    # text_1 = 'blah blah blah'

    def __init__( self, foo = 'bar' ):
        super().__init__()
        self.foo =  foo

        # I can't reference this text from the kv file using "root.title". Why?
        self.text_1 = 'blah blah {foo}'.format( foo = self.foo )

        # I can reference this text from the kv file using "root.title"
        self.title = 'Title {foo}!'.format( foo = self.foo )


class CustomPopupTestApp( App ):
    def build( self ):
        return CustomPopup()


#Instantiate top-level/root widget and run it
if __name__ == "__main__":
    CustomPopupTestApp().run()
```

kv:

```
<CustomPopup>:
    id: popup
    title: root.title
    title_size: 30
    title_align: 'center'
    size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
    auto_dismiss: False
    pos_hint: { 'x' : 0.1 , 'y' : 0.1 }

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 2
        spacing: 15
        padding: 15

        Label:
            id: content
            text: root.text_1
            font_size: 25
            padding: 15, 25
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            height: self.texture_size[ 1 ]
            halign: 'center'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 1

            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x : 'center'
                anchor_y : 'bottom'
                padding: 20

                Button:
                    id: yes
                    text: 'Yes'
                    font_size: 30
                    size_hint: 0.8, 0.4

            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x : 'center'
                anchor_y : 'bottom'
                padding: 20

                Button:
                    id: no
                    text: 'No'
                    font_size: 30
                    size_hint: 0.8, 0.4
```

I would like to setup the text for my pop-up and use the str.format() method to insert a variable text element so that my message is tailored to the circumstances at hand, rather than generic or hard-coded with multiple options.

In this case, I pass an argument of 'foo' to the constructor, set the variable 'self.foo' equal to 'foo', then refer to 'self.foo' within my 'self.title' string and 'self.text_1' string.

If I place 'text_1' outside of the constructor, while I can retrieve the text value, since 'foo' hasn't been defined within that scope, I can't reference it to format my string.

I am interested in other solutions and any opportunity to learn, but ultimately, if there's a way to make this work without a workaround, that would be ideal.

Thanks in advance for any help. I've already learned a ton from everyone on this site.

P.S. - If I've done something "stupid" or offended your sensibilities, please provide a suggestion or correction rather than just berate me. Sometimes people get negative and it's (usually) not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through research and testing, I've found my answers.

It turns out, firstly, that I wasn't calling 'self.title' like I thought I was. Therefore, I wasn't seeing different behavior for 'self.title' vs 'self.text_1'; I was seeing the same behavior. So, how then was I able to get my title to show, but not my content?

The Popup widget has inherent attributes of 'title' and 'content'. When I defined 'self.title' in CustomPopup(), I just provided that attribute's value. Even after removing the corresponding kv code 'title: root.title', the same value defined for 'self.title' was still displayed. This was the crucial moment the clued me in that I was distracted by the red herring of 'self.title' vs 'self.text_1'.

Once I ruled out the issue that I'm seeing different behavior for two otherwise identical lines of code, I looked deeper into how I was defining my CustomPopup class. That's when I came across this post that demonstrated how to handle this properly: [Kivy: How to get class Variables in Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487672/kivy-how-to-get-class-variables-in-popup).

Long story... slightly less long... I updated my super method to inherit my 'text_1' StringProperty so that I could reference it from the CustomPopup object!

Here's the updated working solution:

Python:

```
import kivy
from kivy import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

kivy.require( '1.10.1' )

Config.set( 'graphics', 'fullscreen', 0 )
Config.set( 'graphics', 'height', 600 )
Config.set( 'graphics', 'width', 800 )
Config.set( 'graphics', 'resizable', 0 )
Config.set( 'kivy', 'exit_on_escape', 0 )



class CustomPopup( Popup ):

    text_1 = StringProperty( '' )

    def __init__( self, foo = 'bar' ):
        super( CustomPopup, self ).__init__()

        self.foo =  foo

        self.text_1 =  'blah blah {foo}'.format( foo = self.foo )

        self.title = 'Title {foo}!'.format( foo = self.foo )


class CustomPopupTestApp( App ):
    def build( self ):
        blarg = CustomPopup()
        return blarg


#Instantiate top-level/root widget and run it
if __name__ == "__main__":
    CustomPopupTestApp().run()
```

kv:

```
<CustomPopup>:
    id: popup
    # title: root.title
    title_size: 30
    title_align: 'center'
    size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
    auto_dismiss: False
    pos_hint: { 'x' : 0.1 , 'y' : 0.1 }

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 2
        spacing: 15
        padding: 15

        Label:
            id: content
            text: root.text_1
            font_size: 25
            padding: 15, 25
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            height: self.texture_size[ 1 ]
            halign: 'center'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 1

            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x : 'center'
                anchor_y : 'bottom'
                padding: 20

                Button:
                    id: yes
                    text: 'Yes'
                    font_size: 30
                    size_hint: 0.8, 0.4

            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x : 'center'
                anchor_y : 'bottom'
                padding: 20

                Button:
                    id: no
                    text: 'No'
                    font_size: 30
                    size_hint: 0.8, 0.4
```

Notice that the kv file no longer refers to 'root.title', yet the title is still displayed properly.

The final product pictured in the link below is a Kivy popup with the structure/formatting defined in the kv file with the functionality and variable text defined in Python. It looks much cleaner to me than doing it all on the Python side.

[CustomPopupTest Working Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUQth.png)

I hope this helps someone else like so many other posts have helped me.

Comment: This was another great example of the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373746/kivy-i-want-to-change-an-attribute-of-a-widget-in-a-screen-out-of-a-popup